# Declare d3ddevice global or pass into classes that require it?

Tags: c++, scope, directx-9

DirectX 9 / C++

Do you declare d3ddevice global to your entire app/game or do you pass into classes that require the d3ddevice?

What is the usual way?

I understand it (and this may be wrong) that if you declare it globally, all classes and functions will be burdened by header memory that declares that global variable within the class after compiling?

I can be more specific about my question my application but, I'm just looking for the typical way.

I know how to start the d3ddevice etc, it's just a question about what is best?

Comment: It is kind of annoying trying to keep things local with Direct3D, but I found the problem becomes easier if you wrap what you use up as you go along. Storing the device in a class allows all members to use it without hassle, and all members should be related, so it fits pretty well.

Comment: Can you give me a quick example of what you mean by wrap up. do you mean that you have one direct3d class that handles all drawing? or do you pass a d3ddevice around the place like a filthy hooker?

Comment: When I started going through that again, I created a small `Window` class that had a couple slightly customizable preset windows, a `Direct3D9` class to handle that interface, a `Direct3DDevice9` class for that interface, a `Scene` class for my rendering, and other things like that. Each took care of initialization and destruction, and each wrapped that interface's functions to remove unused parameters and make it more modern C++ish overall.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend you wrap everything within a class and never put anything in global because global variables can be accessed from anywhere and that can make it very hard to keep track of the variable and who is and isn't using it.

Comment: Okay so this is a very typical thing, game programmers would instantiate one directxdevice and object inside lets say a game class and then pass that device into enemy class and player class in order to draw them? or would they have one direct3d class that has very general drawing functions and then call them from the external enemy class or player class for example?

Comment: @JamesT The way I would do it is create a DirectX class that knows how to init it and knows how to draw things based on parameters you pass in. You than create a player class and when it comes to drawing it you would pass in parameters to the DirectX (Things like pos, Shader file, texture file) class telling it how it should draw the object. This way it will separate your game logic from your drawing logic.

Comment: thanks for that. That makes complete sense to me. You're a saint

Comment: @rwols - Is there any memory issues with making it global though? As stated in my OP, I was imagining that all classes are compiled with some header that points at the d3d object regardless of if they need it?

Comment: @rwols It is a free world, you can do what you like. But I can speak from experience that once the project becomes big it will become incredibly hard to track the global variables and it will make your life hell.

Answer (score 0):

Little bit late to the party here, but I also just recently stumbled into this same design question. It's a little surprising to me that there isn't more talk about it on the internet. I even tried perusing random github libraries to see if I could glean how others did it. Didn't find much. I also have an example of when you can't declare the d3d device as a global/static object. For my game/engine, I have a dll which serves as my engine framework. This dll is consumed by both an editor, and a game client (what people will use to play my game). This allows both things (and other applications in the future if desired) to access all of the world objects, math code, collections, etc.

With that system, I can't think of a way to make the Device object static, and still use it in both the editor and the client. If this were just a game client, or just an editor, then sure, it would be possible. Instead, I've pretty much decided to bite the bullet and pass Device to whatever needs it. One example, is a class that generates vertices at runtime. I need a pointer to Device for rebuilding the class.

I really just wanted to post this here, because I've been thinking about it for most of the day, and it really seems like this is the best way to handle it. Yeah, it sucks to have to pass the Device to nearly everything. But there's not really anything you can do about it.

Comment: If this helps, might just be worth using Unreal Engine given it's 2021, hehehe :) . Good luck though dude!

Comment: @Jimmyt1988 No thanks, I'm making my own game engine; paying royalties is for chumps. https://imgur.com/a/AhEaX5u